# Log flood "W/ActivityManager is using old GET_TASKS but privileged"

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Running React Native I can't stop getting these error logs:

```
 W/ActivityManager: getTasks: caller 10006 is using old GET_TASKS but privileged; allowing
```

[image: Message log]

If there a way to hide it or fix it?